# How to make so not all components are called on page load in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I was working on a React app and finally came to point to check if app needs some optimization which in my case it apparently seem to be lots of optimization.

The current performance score with this code is 12% and if i removed almost everything from import and ofc not use those comopnents the performance score goes to 70%, so my question is is this loading all components when the app is loading eventhou The components were supposed to be loaded or rendered only when I go to specific route, does React loads all of this, is there any mechanism to just load what needed at this point and than only load components when going to specific route!

Any tips on how to optimize the current code? Does the current impl loads all components so basically all the javascript code on every page load?
Thank you

Comment: You can go with either code splitting or you can control when to show the component. By using intersection observer. Simple and less weight library(~3kb). https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-observer-api

Comment: i dont really like to rely on a library that has 100 of downloads weekly, but thanks for ur effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your questions:

> is this loading all components when the app is loading eventhou The components were supposed to be loaded or rendered only when I go to specific route? does React loads all of this?

Yes, as the current code looks like, you (not react) are loading all components at once, meaning your bundle is huge!

> is there any mechanism to just load what needed at this point and than only load components when going to specific route!

Yes, there's this pattern called `Code Splitting` where you tell webpack to create smaller bundles, each for every route, then you load each bundle when the user navigates to each route.

Code splitting is fairly simple nowadays (I remember doing this manually back in 2009 )

In a nutshell:

1. You need to enable code splitting in webpack by install a couple plugins:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

2. You need to use a module loader, to dynamically load your code (https://github.com/smooth-code/loadable-components)
3. Import the loader and a loading animation component.

```
import loadable from "@loadable/component";
import Loading from "./Loading.js"; // A spinner or something you want
```

4. Lazy load your components, for example:

```
const MyProfileAsync = loadable(() => import("./modules/Applicant/Components/MyProfile"), {
  fallback: <Loading />
});
```

5. Set a route for your module

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" exact>
    <MyProfileAsync />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Here's a link to a guide using `react-router-dom`: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting

Comment: Hi, thank you alot, this is very detailed answer! appreciate it!

Comment: btw I dont use webpack, so are you suggesting to add webpack in my project and do the above steps? I find webpack abit complex, is there any other alternative tot this?