# Avoid SASS-files being imported globally Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, sass

In my file **Home.tsx** containing components for my Home-page I import a SASS-file like this:

```
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.sass"
```

**Home.module.sass**

```
#container
    width: 100%
    height: 100vh
    display: block
    overflow: auto


#container > div
    width: 50%
    float: left
    height: 100%
    display: flex
    padding: 0 50px
    align-items: center
    box-sizing: border-box
    flex-direction: column
    justify-content: center

...
```

In Home.tsx I use the CSS-classes like this:

```
   <span className={styles.title}>Welcome {user.name}</span>
```

The reason I use '[modules](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-use-sass-and-css-modules-with-create-react-app-83fa8b805e5e)' is because I don't want to import my SASS globally.

In **Panel.tsx** I import other SASS-files:

```
import "../styles/Panel.sass"
import "../styles/Popup.sass"
```

The problem is that even in Panel.tsx the CSS of Home.module.sass is imported even while I don't actually import it. I guess the SASS-files are globally imported. How do I avoid this? I tried using 'modules' but that obviously didn't work.

I guess I could make a parent in Home.module.sass like `.home-page` and use a container `<div className="home-page>` in Home.tsx but that doesn't seems optimal.

How to avoid SASS-files being imported globally?

Comment: i have a suspicion that this might be caused from `app.tsx` where the  routs are, share them with us if possible.

Comment: Are you using NextJs? If yes then which kind of routing types? I think there is a problem with your root importing styles. Something is a little bit peculiar because if you used `css-module` then it would have the local ident name and it would avoid CSS conflicts. So this is weird that you are seeing your Home styles in the Panel component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might be caused from `App.tsx/app.jsx` my answer will use `app.jsx` i ma not too hot at Typescript.

i hade a smiler problem recently where elements are being styled by css that is not imported, after tracing the cause here's what i found.

### possible cause + explanation

in my router i call all the pages/components to return them for each rout:

```js
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./pages/auth/Login.jsx";
import Home from "./pages/Home.jsx";
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

inspecting the sources in the dev tools this is what it looks like

[image: dev tools on login home imported, why?]

even though i am in the login page, all the files i mention in the router are being loaded, and any `CSS` within these files is also being loaded, this is where the conflict happens.

but look what happens if i comment home routs, remember i am on login page.
[image: dev tools on login home commented out]

They are not imported anymore!!!

So we want to tell react not to load any other component/page other than the one i am currently at. but how?

the way i found out was by googling "react calling all components not one", and i came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503804/how-to-make-so-not-all-components-are-called-on-page-load-in-react-app),  this is the [github repo](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components) for the loadable lib too, i encourage you to visit this question cuz it basically has everything i want to say.

but here's how i implemented it anyway:

### solution

```js
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import loadable from "@loadable/component";

const Home = loadable(() => import("./pages/Home.jsx")); // wrap with a loadable
const Login = loadable(() => import("./pages/auth/Login.jsx"));

function App() {
  return ( //remains the same
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

and, it works like a charm, check this out:

[image: dev tools with loadable]

i have all routs i want to declare, and its only loading the rout i am at.

this is all assuming that this `App.jsx/tsx` is the root of your problem, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below solution? Hope it will work for you.

You have written code like below

```
#container > div
    width: 50%
    float: left
    height: 100%
....
```

this will apply all the direct child `div` of the `#container`, instead of this you have to give a specific class to that `div` element that may resolve your problem, for eg.

```
#container > .child-element
    width: 50%
    float: left
    height: 100%
    display: flex
    ...
```

you have to share a more detailed code or codesandbox link for a perfect solution.